# Составление правильной структуры База данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Посоветуйте грамотною структуру таблицы, то есть как лучше сделать.
У меня есть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем информацию "url","title","description" и эти 3 **столбца** могут входить в "article","news","gta". То есть одна запись может быть в article, вторая во new, 3 в gta. Как лучше построить? Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Почитайте про нормализацию базы данных и приведите её к 3 нормальной форме. [Ссылка на хабр](https://habr.com/post/254773/)

Comment: Имхо, достаточно одной таблицы с 4 колонками: address, title, category, description. Что тут ещё выдумывать?

Comment: Идеальный вопрос содержал бы DDL скрипты создания таблиц и связей. Но для начала хоть объясните, что такое `"article","news","gta"`. GTA - это же игра такая, да? А вопрос вроде не по ней.

Answer (score 0):

Если одна страница может иметь один раздел:

- Таблица A: Содержит информацию о разделах.
- Таблица B: Содержит информацию о странице и ID раздела.

---

Если одна страница может иметь много разделов:

- Таблица A: Содержит информацию о разделах.
- Таблица B: Содержит информацию о страницах.
- Таблица A_B: Содержит ID страницы и ID раздела.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделала это так:

```
// Таблица для всех адресов страниц

| addresses | 
|-----------|
| id        |
| name      |

 // Таблица для всех разделов страницы

| topics    |
|-----------|
| id        |
| name      |

// Таблица, которая все объединяет

| articles        | 
|-----------------|
| id              |
| id_address      |
| id_topic        |
| title           |
| description     |
```

Думаю стоит обосновать мое решение того, почему я вынес адреса страниц и темы статей в отдельный таблицы... Для этого представим ситуацию того, что все находится в одной таблице и там накопилось большое количество данных (стоит отметить факт того, что у большинства полей в таблице будут одинаковые темы и адреса страниц). И вот к примеру нам нужно изменить тему "Статьи" на "Рассказы", либо изменить адрес страницы, то в данной ситуации придется проходить по всей таблице и менять искомые данные. Сложность данного подхода будет составлять O(n). А вот если использовать мою структуры то придется изменить одну запись в таблице "addresses", либо в "topics" в зависимости от ситуации и на этом все, тем самым сложность данного подхода будет составлять O(1).

Comment: Все не так. Во-первых, при объемах, когда производительность становится существенным фактором, у вас будут индексы, а поиск в индексе - это `O(log(n))`, а не `O(n)`. А `O(1)` - вообще непонятно, откуда вы взяли.

Comment: Если вы будете искать определенный элемент то сложность будет O(log(n)), но а в данной ситуации вам не нужен поиск, вам просто необходим префиксный проход по всему B+ дереву(таблице) с изменение каждого его звена, на нужное значение, поэтому сложность будет O(n). O(1) - сложность изменения одного поля в таблице "addresses" или "topics".